# trying to figure out why a for each statement worked with an if statement, but throws an exception when i switch it to a for loop

Tags: for-loop, foreach, ms-word, copy-paste, mailmerge

Sorry in advance, as I have only been working with C# for about a month with limited history in VB years ago.  It's a Mail merge kind of loop that I am trying to create for work to make their life easier. I have the dates figured out. I have a NumUpDown control setting the int `myInt`, and a `formCount` int starting at 0.
The code worked fine when I used `if(formCount==0),` when I switched it to

```
for(formCount=0;formCount<myInt;formCount++)
```

it now throws a

> "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'"

I know there is probably another way to do what I am working on which is to just add sequential dates to forms a month at a time.  I have the dates stored in an array `myDate[31]`.

I am using the `numUpDwn(min 1 max 31)` to get `myInt` so we can select how many days in the month, or only print a couple days if we need to replace pages, so we can print anywhere from 1 to 31 pages.

With the if statement it would create the first page from the template `(.dotx)` to `doc(var)` copy the contents of doc to doc2 and add a new page to receive the next content paste.

I am sure this is a silly question, that someone will have a simple answer too.  The loop is supposed to open the template, add the date, copy to doc2. close the original, and restart until it reached the number of pages/dates selected.  Thanks for any help, this is the last section I need to finish and I am stumped. Oh, and I used the != because it was skipping the merge field, but with only 1 field not equal to anything worked.

```
private void BtnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
           var doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
           var doc2 = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
           //app.Visible = true;
           doc = null;
           doc2.PageSetup.Orientation = WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;
           doc2.PageSetup.TopMargin = app.InchesToPoints(0.6f);
           doc2.PageSetup.BottomMargin = app.InchesToPoints(0.17f);
           doc2.PageSetup.LeftMargin = app.InchesToPoints(0.5f);
           doc2.PageSetup.RightMargin = app.InchesToPoints(0.5f);
           String fileSave;
           fileSave = ("OTSU" + "_" + myDate[0].Month + "_" + myDate[0].Year + ".docx");
           
           
           int formCount;
           //formCount = 0;
           var filepath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + outfile;
           doc = app.Documents.Add(filepath);
           
           doc2.Activate();
           //OBJECT OF MISSING "NULL VALUE"
           Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
           for (formCount = 0; formCount<myInt;formCount++)
           {
               doc.Activate();

               foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Field field in doc.Fields)
               {

                   Range rngFieldCode = field.Code;
                   String fieldText = rngFieldCode.Text;
                   // ONLY GETTING THE MAILMERGE FIELDS
                   if (fieldText.StartsWith(" MERGEFIELD"))
                   {
                       Int32 endMerge = fieldText.IndexOf("\\");
                       Int32 fieldNameLength = fieldText.Length - endMerge;
                       String fieldName = fieldText.Substring(11);
                       // GIVES THE FIELDNAMES AS THE USER HAD ENTERED IN .dotx FILE
                       fieldName = fieldName.Trim();
                       if (fieldName != "M_2nd__3rd")
                       {
                           field.Select();
                           app.Selection.TypeText(myDate[formCount].ToShortDateString());
                       }
                       formCount++;
                       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range dRange = doc.Content;
                       dRange.Copy();
                       
                       doc2.Range(doc2.Content.End - 1, doc2.Content.End - 1).PasteSpecial(DataType: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPasteOptions.wdKeepSourceFormatting);
                       doc2.Range(doc2.Content.End - 1, doc2.Content.End - 1).InsertBreak(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak);
                       Clipboard.Clear();
                       doc.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
                   }

               }
           }
           doc2.SaveAs2("OTSU" + myDate[0].Month + "_" + myDate[0].Year + ".docx");
           app.Documents.Open("OTSU" + myDate[0].Month + "_" + myDate[0].Year + ".docx");
           doc.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
           doc2.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a solution for now. Since there is only one MERGFIELD, instead of trying to open doc, insert date, copy to new doc2, close doc, repeat I found I can open, insert date, copy to new doc2, undo edit on doc and repeat.  At least it works for now, and I can get back to the books and learn some more while I map out the big project I have planned.  I am sure I will be on here a bit with more questions.  Without @slightly-snarky asking the questions he did, I wouldn't have thought of this so I have to give them credit for the answer. I did have to put the doc.Undo(); at the top of the loop and it will only work with one field.  But its a start.

```
     private void BtnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        String fileSave;
        fileSave = ("OTSU" + "_" + myDate[0].Month + "_" + myDate[0].Year + ".docx");
        int formCount;
        formCount = 0;
        var filepath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + outfile;
        var doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
        doc = app.Documents.Add(filepath);
        app.Visible = true;
        doc.Activate();
        var doc2 = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
        doc2.PageSetup.Orientation = WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;
        doc2.PageSetup.TopMargin = app.InchesToPoints(0.6f);
        doc2.PageSetup.BottomMargin = app.InchesToPoints(0.17f);
        doc2.PageSetup.LeftMargin = app.InchesToPoints(0.5f);
        doc2.PageSetup.RightMargin = app.InchesToPoints(0.5f);

        doc2.Activate();
        //OBJECT OF MISSING "NULL VALUE"
        Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        for (formCount = 0; formCount < myInt; formCount++)
        {
            doc.Undo();
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Field field in doc.Fields)
            {
                Range rngFieldCode = field.Code;
                String fieldText = rngFieldCode.Text;
                // ONLY GETTING THE MAILMERGE FIELDS
                if (fieldText.StartsWith(" MERGEFIELD"))
                {
                    Int32 endMerge = fieldText.IndexOf("\\");
                    Int32 fieldNameLength = fieldText.Length - endMerge;
                    String fieldName = fieldText.Substring(11);
                    // GIVES THE FIELDNAMES AS THE USER HAD ENTERED IN .dotx FILE
                    fieldName = fieldName.Trim();
                    if (fieldName != "M_2nd__3rd")
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        app.Selection.TypeText(myDate[formCount].ToShortDateString());
                    }
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range dRange = doc.Content;
                    dRange.Copy();
                    doc2.Range(doc2.Content.End - 1, doc2.Content.End - 1).PasteSpecial(DataType: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPasteOptions.wdKeepSourceFormatting);
                    doc2.Range(doc2.Content.End - 1, doc2.Content.End - 1).InsertBreak(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak);
                    Clipboard.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
        doc2.SaveAs2("OTSU" + myDate[0].Month + "_" + myDate[0].Year + ".docx");
        doc.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
        doc2.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
        app.Documents.Open("OTSU" + myDate[0].Month + "_" + myDate[0].Year + ".docx");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t run your code, but as far as I can see, this code would probably fail even without the formcount loop in the situation where you have more than one MERGEFIELD field because you close `doc` As soon as you have processed such a field, and yet the foreach loop is processing each Field in doc.Fields.

Even if that foreach loop terminates gracefully, in the next iteration of the formCount loop you are using `doc.Activate()`, but `doc` has closed so that will fail.

So I suggest that the main thing to do is consider which documents need to be open at which point for the process to work.

Some observations (not necessarily to do with your primary question)

- where is myInt set?
- is having a formCount++ loop *and* using formCount++ within the loop for every MERGEFIELD in `doc` Really your intention?
- you might be better off testing field.Type() when filtering MAILMERGE fields rather than matching the text, at least if such fields can be set up by end users
- when you process collections in Word and you are either adding or deleting members of the collection, you sometimes have to consider using a loop that starts with last member of the collection and works back towards the beginning. Not sure you need to do that in this case but since you may be “deleting” when you do your field.Select then Typetext, please bear that in mind
- It may seem like a complication when you are mainly trying to sketch out the logic of your loops, but I generally find it very helpful to start using try...catch...finally blocks sooner rather than later during development.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and catching that second formCount++.  I thought I had commented that out when I put in the for statement.  myInt is set by the nudDays (number up down control) on the form with a max of 31 and min of 1.
I have the original document as a Word template that doesn't overwrite. It always opens as a new document. I figured I was overwriting the field. which is why I was activating doc. insert date. copy to new doc2. close doc. then start with activating doc again until formCount=myInt. I may have to try it another way for the merge and figure out how to write and used methods

Comment: I'm not willing to spend money on a utility for merging for a program that is simply to put dates on signup sheets for a month at a time.  Just trying to simplify it for the 2 people that print them once a month.  I do appreciate you help and input though.  I will go back to one of the 2 books I read and look at what it said about try...catch...finally blocks.

Comment: @Eric just for clarification, what I’m saying is that you are closing doc *within* the foreach loop that is accessing doc, and you don’t create a new *doc* before the next iteration of your formCount loop, because you create doc before the beginning of that loop.

Comment: I saw what you were saying.  That was definitely an error on my part.  I had it correct in the else if and the else statements I had commented out. But I missed it in the If statement which is where it was throwing the exception.  I will play with it a bit more.  While it is working now, I can see if I can clean up some of my code and experiment with it on a backup copy.  I am sure it will take a few days before I will get approval to take it into work.  So I can see if I can improve upon it in the meantime.